# Create an object with mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I can console.log the object that I want, but how can I retrieve the object outside of connection.query()?

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require("mysql");

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 50,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "sakila"
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM actor', function(err, rows) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var user = rows[0];
    console.log(user);

  });

  res.send();
});
```

This is the result in the console:

```
node-databases> node .\database\db-1.js
RowDataPacket {
  actor_id: 1,
  first_name: 'PENELOPE',
  last_name: 'GUINESS',
  last_update: 2006-02-15T10:34:33.000Z }
```

I want to be able to take that and send it in the response to the browser.

Comment: Replace `console.log` with `res.send` thus sending response within the callback

Comment: You're a genius! I actually figured this out while trying Knex, and when you told me about that it all made sense. Thank you!!! Write that as an answer and I'll give you some internet points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `console.log` with `res.send` thus sending response within the callback.